# RAS API. sizeof(RASDIALPARAMS) is wrong. Error 632

Tags: c++, c, winapi, size, ras

I'm working with RAS API under Windows 7 x32. The following function returns error 632 (ERROR_INVALID_SIZE):

```
int32_t set_username_passwd(wchar_t *entry_title)
{
    RASDIALPARAMS ras_param;
    ZeroMemory(&ras_param, sizeof(RASDIALPARAMS));
    ras_param.dwSize = sizeof(RASDIALPARAMS);
    memcpy(ras_param.szEntryName, entry_title, wcslen(entry_title));
    memcpy(ras_param.szUserName, L"username", wcslen(L"username"));
    memcpy(ras_param.szPassword, L"password", wcslen(L"password"));
    return RasSetEntryDialParams(0, &ras_param, 0);
}
```

`sizeof(RASDIALPARAMS)` returns wrong size? How could it be?

Or what am i missing?

Comment: Quote: "Windows XP or later:  Do not use the RasSetEntryDialParams function"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RASDIALPARAMS` has had new fields added to it over the years:

```
#define RASDIALPARAMSW struct tagRASDIALPARAMSW
RASDIALPARAMSW
{
    DWORD dwSize;
    WCHAR szEntryName[ RAS_MaxEntryName + 1 ];
    WCHAR szPhoneNumber[ RAS_MaxPhoneNumber + 1 ];
    WCHAR szCallbackNumber[ RAS_MaxCallbackNumber + 1 ];
    WCHAR szUserName[ UNLEN + 1 ];
    WCHAR szPassword[ PWLEN + 1 ];
    WCHAR szDomain[ DNLEN + 1 ];
#if (WINVER >= 0x401) // 95/NT4 and later
    DWORD dwSubEntry;
    ULONG_PTR dwCallbackId;
#endif
#if (WINVER >= 0x601) // Windows 7 and later
    DWORD dwIfIndex;
#endif
};
```

As such, the size of `RASDIALPARAMS` that `RasSetEntryDialParams()` expects depends on the particular Windows version.  But the actual size of `RASDIALPARAMS` inside of your app depends on the `WINVER` define during compiling, as seen above.

So, when targeting Windows 7, `WINVER` must be set to a value that is at least `0x601` (Windows 7 is v6.1).  If you compile with a lower `WINVER` value then the size of `RASDIALPARAMS` will be too small for Windows 7 to accept.

If you set `WINVER` to a higher value than the Windows version that you are targeting, you can detect the OS version at runtime and set `ras_param.dwSize` to the appropriate size since `sizeof(RASDIALPARAMS)` will be larger than what `RasSetEntryDialParams()` is expecting.  For example:

```
int32_t set_username_passwd(wchar_t *entry_title)
{
    RASDIALPARAMSW ras_param;
    ZeroMemory(&ras_param, sizeof(ras_param));

    OSVERSIONINFO osvi;
    ZeroMemory(&osvi, sizeof(osvi));

    GetVersionEx(&osvi);

    #if (WINVER >= 0x401)
    if ((osvi.dwMajorVersion < 4) ||
       ((osvi.dwMajorVersion == 4) && (osvi.dwMinVersion < 1)) )
    {
        ras_param.dwSize = offsetof(RASDIALPARAMSW, dwSubEntry);
    }
    else
    #endif
    #if (WINVER >= 0x601)
    if ((osvi.dwMajorVersion < 6) ||
       ((osvi.dwMajorVersion == 6) && (osvi.dwMinVersion < 1)) )
    {
        ras_param.dwSize = offsetof(RASDIALPARAMSW, dwIfIndex);
    }
    else
    #endif
    {
        ras_param.dwSize = sizeof(ras_param);
    }

    wcsncpy(ras_param.szEntryName, entry_title, RAS_MaxEntryName);
    wcsncpy(ras_param.szUserName, L"username", UNLEN);
    wcsncpy(ras_param.szPassword, L"password", PWLEN);

    return RasSetEntryDialParamsW(0, &ras_param, 0);
}
```

Alternatively, you can skip the OS check and just handle the `ERROR_INVALID_SIZE` error instead:

```
int32_t set_username_passwd(wchar_t *entry_title)
{
    RASDIALPARAMSW ras_param;
    ZeroMemory(&ras_param, sizeof(ras_param));

    ras_param.dwSize = sizeof(ras_param);
    wcsncpy(ras_param.szEntryName, entry_title, RAS_MaxEntryName);
    wcsncpy(ras_param.szUserName, L"username", UNLEN);
    wcsncpy(ras_param.szPassword, L"password", PWLEN);

    DWORD dwRet = RasSetEntryDialParamsW(0, &ras_param, 0);
    #if (WINVER >= 0x601)
    if (dwRet == ERROR_INVALID_SIZE)
    {
        ras_param.dwSize = offsetof(RASDIALPARAMSW, dwIfIndex);
        dwRet = RasSetEntryDialParamsW(0, &ras_param, 0);
    }
    #elif (WINVER >= 0x401)
    if (dwRet == ERROR_INVALID_SIZE)
    {
        ras_param.dwSize = offsetof(RASDIALPARAMSW, dwSubEntry);
        dwRet = RasSetEntryDialParamsW(0, &ras_param, 0);
    }
    #endif

    return dwRet;
}
```